# Use MS Access 2010 to attach a file in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, blob, ms-access-2010

I checked for few days how to do this and I'm getting close to the solution, but I still can't find how to do it.

1. Back-end is MySQL and I have a table called Product with
   different fields, one of them being Datasheet (BLOB data type)
2. Front-end is MS Access 2010, and connects to database through ODBC.
3. I'm using mostly bound forms to add new records to the tables.

So far what I've got is a form where you input all the data for each field of Product table. At the end of it I have a "Attachment" field (made by wizard), I created an event:

```
Private Sub Attachment_Click() as String
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select file to attach"
    If .show = True Then
        SelectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If
End With
Set fd = Nothing
End Function
```

So this will return the path of the file.

Now, when I click the button Save of my form, I basically declare the form
   Me.Dirty
So the fields are automatically updated to the database. But the attachment doesn't upload.

I checked: [Add/view attachments using MS Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237180/add-view-attachments-using-ms-access-vba). This is great, but I am missing how to specifically tell to MySQL by using VBA which row it should add the information to. I am thinking using the Form_AfterUpate() to do the rutine, so then I know that all the other fields have been already saved.