# Add/View OLEObjects using MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, createoleobject

Based on [Add/view attachments using MS Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237180/add-view-attachments-using-ms-access-vba) is there a way to act the same way but this time for OLEObjects? How can we replace the `AddAttachment` method?

Answer (score 0):

Review this reference for method to import OLEObject [Import OLEObject](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=186617). Quite a bit of code involved. Download the sample db and start with review of this proc:

```
Sub SaveFileToBlob(OLEPath, OLEName)
Dim Tbl As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set Tbl = New ADODB.Recordset
    With Tbl
        .Open "TblEmbeddedObjects", MasterDbConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
        .AddNew
        .Fields("fldDocumentName").Value = OLEName
         FileToBlob OLEPath & OLEName, .Fields("fldDocument")
        .Fields("fldDocumentDate") = Date
        .Fields("fldDestinationPath") = Replace(OLEPath, "\\", "\")
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
    Set Tbl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Uses methods AppendChunk and GetChunk. Review [Manage OLEObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822448.aspx)