# Add Attachment to Access DB using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have been researching for the past couple hours and had no luck finding a solution to this. What I want to do is have users fill a user form from Excel and submit the data to Access but one of the fields requires a screenshot which is essentially an attachment. I have been trying two sets of codes (DAO and ADODB). I am able to submit any other datatype to Access easily using the ADODB connection but not an attachment. Below are my 2 codes:

```
    Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select file to attach"
        If .Show = True Then
            SelectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Set fd = Nothing

Dim NewCon As DAO.Database
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim strFileName As String
Dim wrkAcc As Workspace

Set NewCon = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\my.user\Documents\Database1.accdb")
Set RS = OpenRecordset("REPORTS", dbOpenTable)

RS.Edit

RS.Fields("NAME").Value = Application.UserName
RS.Fields("DATE_REPORT").Value = Date
RS.Fields("CLAIM_TYPE").Value = "Fielda"
RS.Fields("CLIENT_NAME").Value = "Fieldb"
RS.Fields("ISSUE").Value = "Fieldc"
RS.Fields("REPORT_NUMBERS").Value = "Fieldd"
'RS.Fields("ATTACHMENTS").      (this is where I want to place the attachment)
RS.Fields("LOG_TIME").Value = Now

RS.Close
NewCon.Close

End Sub
```

This is the ADODB:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()


    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select file to attach"
        If .Show = True Then
            SelectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Set fd = Nothing

        Dim NewCon As ADODB.Connection
        Set NewCon = New ADODB.Connection
        Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
        Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset

        NewCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\my.user\Documents\Database1.accdb"
        Recordset.Open "REPORTS", NewCon, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        Recordset.AddNew

        Recordset.Fields(1).Value = Application.UserName
        Recordset.Fields(2).Value = Date
        Recordset.Fields(3).Value = "Fielda"
        Recordset.Fields(4).Value = "Fieldb"
        Recordset.Fields(5).Value = "Fieldc"
        Recordset.Fields(6).Value = "Fieldd"
'       Recordset.Fields(6) (this is where I want to place the attachment)
        Recordset.Fields(8).Value = Now

        Recordset.Update
        Recordset.Close
        NewCon.Close

        End Sub
```

Comment: Try google: "access database insert image vba"

Comment: @Sorceri If you have a dupe, then mark it as such. Else, I'd say we can have it here too. The closest dupe I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237180/add-view-attachments-using-ms-access-vba), but the relevant code is linked and the link is dead.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  third link down was the solution, the point is they couldn't have searched that hard if I can find it in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

DAO is the easiest way to work with attachment in my opinion.

The attachment field is actually a subtable, which can be opened as a recordset. You can work with the field like with any recordset. The `"FileData"` field stores a compressed version of the files in the attachment field.

You can call the `LoadFromFile` method to load a new file into the `"FileData"` field, or the `SaveToFile` method to save back the attachment to disk.

There are some other fields in that recordset, such as the filename, which are auto-populated when you use the `LoadFromFile` method

Some changes need to be made.

Value initializations need to use `DAO.Recordset2` to support attachments:

```
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsAttachments As DAO.Recordset2
```

Assignment section, use the inner recordset:

```
RS.Fields("REPORT_NUMBERS").Value = "Fieldd"
Set rsAttachments = RS.Fields("ATTACHMENTS").Value
rsAttachments.AddNew
rsAttachments.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile SelectFile
rsAttachments.Update
rsAttachments.Close
RS.Fields("LOG_TIME").Value = Now
```