# Setting path in Access Attachment Manager dialog

Tags: vba, ms-access, attachment

We're using an Attachment control on our forms. Clicking the control opens this built-in dialog:

[image]

It works fine, but is there a way to set the default path that is uses?  (Preferably without having to build a custom version of the form myself.)

PS: I know that it would be better to save files outside of the database instead of using attachment fields, but we have to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

For each install of Access, go to **File > Options > General > Default database folder** and set it to whichever folder to be default. The Attachment dialog will use this as default path.

Otherwise, use VBA and FileDialog to manage attachments. This is a fairly common topic and numerous examples on web - here is one from SO: [Add/view attachments using MS Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237180/add-view-attachments-using-ms-access-vba)